# Upload a file with GraphQL and Dropzone

Tags: javascript, upload, graphql, dropzone.js, apollo-server

I would like to know how can I upload a file to the API with GraphQL.

Currently when I log the file, I have this :

[image]

But when I execute the mutation, I have this error "400 Bad Request" :

[image]

In my component :

```
<dropzone id="foo" ref="el" :options="options" @vdropzone-file-added="sendingFile"></dropzone>

...

sendingFile(file) {
  console.log(file)

  this.$store
    .dispatch('post/uploadPostImage', file)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('Succes : Upload file')
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('Error')
    })
},
```

> My service :

uploadFile(client, file) {
console.log(file)

```
  return client
     .mutate({
        mutation: uploadFile,
        variables: {
           file,
        },
        fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
     })
     .then(({ data }) => {
        return data.uploadFile
     })
     .catch((error) => {
        throw new Error(error.message)
     })
  },
```

}

> My uploadFile mutation :

```
const uploadFile = gql`
    mutation($file: Upload) {
    uploadFile(file: $file) {
        filename
        mimetype
        encoding
   }
 }
`
```

On the API, in the schema

```
type Mutation {
    # Upload
    uploadFile(file: Upload!): File!
}

type File {
    filename: String!
    mimetype: String!
    encoding: String!
}
```

I use apollo-server-express

Comment: FormData is not an error, it's proper graphql upload request

Comment: Thank you @xadm for your comment. I have this error : 400 Bad Request

Comment: check if server properly supports uploads and why this mutation fails (debug resolver)

Comment: First of all in your schema file input is mandatory, while in client side mutation it is non mandatory, it may cause error, also according to screenshot in variables file is null. Please check data being passed to server call

Comment: @PranjalKoshti null for files is normal for upload (multipart/formdata ... check 'graphql upload specs'); you're right that query should strictly follow API specs ... then `uploadFile` fragment should be updated to `mutation($file: Upload!) {`

Comment: Thank you @PranjalKoshti ! It's ok now, I updated my code. You can post a new answer ! I check that !

Answer (score 0):

You need to install client dependencies and then update your client `createUploadLink` instead of `HttpLink`.

```
npm install apollo-upload-client
```

To hook it up, we need to replace the `HttpLink` Link instance with a Link created by using the apollo-upload-client‘s `createUploadLink` factory function.

Reference: https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql/file-uploads/with-react-hooks-typescript-amazon-s3-tutorial/